# 403 Forbidden Error on Azure Linux virtual machine

Tags: linux, virtual-machines, azure

I am trying to access the freshly created virtual machine on azure via winscp and putty, through putty I am able to access the VM but via winscp I get following error,

Proxy Error: 403 Forbidden.

I have deployed Ubuntu 14.04 VM on Azure Cloud and whenever I try to access it behind a proxy server I got above mentioned error.

Comment: So, you're behind a proxy trying to access it? Ask the proxy administrators as they probably block outgoing SSH on your network.

Comment: If they were blocking it I wouldn't be able to access the VM on putty on same ip and port. But the thing is I am only getting this on WinScp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured the answer, the Squid proxy server was corrupted and that's why it was giving me error like I was able to send traffic on to 22 and 21 port at one moment and couldn't do it on other, I updated the file and edited the conf file to add the rule. Worked for me.